# Reapply labels for email reply / forwards

Tags: thunderbird

I am using the labelling / tagging (I do not know the exact translation, it's "Schlagwörter" in German) of Thunderbird to filter my mails.

When I reply to an email or forward it, I would like to have the sent message, stored in my *Sent* folder, labelled with the same tags/labels as the original incoming message.

Is that somehow possible?

As an alternative, I thought about a filter condition like "Messages that are replies to messages that are labelled like xyz", but I could not find that as well.